# Создание подклассов в С++

Tags: c++, наследование

Нужно написать консольное приложение, которое выводит список товаров. Свойства товара: название, цена, штрих-код. Категория товара, например книги, у книг есть количество страниц. Подскажите, почему у меня не выводится количество страниц?

```
class Goods
    {
    private:
        string Name;
        double Price;
        string Code;

    public:
        void SetInitial(string InputName, double InputPrice, string InputCode)
        {
            Name=InputName;
            Price=InputPrice;
            Code=InputCode;
        }

        void GetInfo()
        {
            cout << "Name: " + Name << endl;
            cout << "Price: " << Price << endl;
            cout << "Code: " + Code << endl;
        }
    };

    class Book:public Goods
    {
    private:
        unsigned int Pages;

    public:
        void SetPages(unsigned int InputPages)
        {
            Pages=InputPages;
        }

        void GetPages()
        {
            cout << "Count of Pages: " + Pages << endl;
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        Book First;
        First.SetInitial("Book1", 300.5, "1569K");
        First.GetInfo();
        First.SetPages(300);
        First.GetPages();
    }
```

Comment: А что делает выражение `"Count of Pages: " + Pages` в методе `GetPages`?, Думаю надо `cout << "Count of Pages: " << Pages << endl;`;
`

Comment: Видимо скопировал и не заметил ошибку, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас переменная Pages целочисленная, а Вы пытаетесь с ней работать как со строкой.

Поэтому либо так

```
void GetPages()
{
    cout << "Count of Pages: " + to_string(Pages) << endl;
}
```

Либо так

```
void GetPages()
{
    cout << "Count of Pages: " << Pages << endl;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, еще такой вопрос, можно ли в базовый класс перемещать свойства производных классов и делать доступными определенные методы (friend), или все-таки нужно создавать производные классы со своим списком инициализации? но тогда при вызове очень много строк.

Comment: Вы можете сделать класс отнаследованный от нескольких интерфейсов с тем наборов свойств который нужен в конкретной ситуации. Потом после создании Вы можете приводится к нужному интерфейсу и работать с объектом ограниченным набором свойств конкретного интерфейса.

Comment: Можете посоветовать литературу по этой теме? Буду очень признателен.

Comment: Ну если Вас интересуют вопросы проектирования то могу посоветовать почитать о паттернах - "Приемы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны проектирования"